# Sequence Diagram for Response Redirect in ASP.Net Webforms

Tags: asp.net, uml

In asp.net webforms I have a home aspx page that has a “Go” button. [This is the only control in this page]. When this button is clicked, the user is redirected to “UserProfile.aspx” page.  How can we represent this redirect action in sequence diagram? Any reference articles/blogs for this?

Answer (score 4):

It is a bit strange to do it this way, because what do you try to tell your audience ? I would not use a sequence diagram for this but make a navigation map.

If you really want to do it, below is what Visual Studio can generate :

[image]